# Rails 4 - serving an image from the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get some avatars om my users but can't seem to serve images from the public folder.

to make it simple I have a file in

```
RAILS_ROOT/public/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg
```

I try to serve it with:

```
%img{:src=>"/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg"}
```

in my prowser it is rendered as:

```
<img src="/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg">
```

which translates to (I think):

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg
```

I[image]

I have checked permissions on the folder.
I have flicked the folling setting in development.rb:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

No change.

My routes are - according to rake routes:

```
        Rails.application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users

      concern :paginatable do
        get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''
      end



      match 'albums/select' => 'albums/select', via: [:get, :post]
      #get 'albums/show_stat' => 'albums#show_stat'
      resources :albums, :concerns => :paginatable


      match "photos/(year/:year)/(month/:month)/(day/:day)/(country/:country)" => "photos#index", :via => [:post, :get]
      resources :photos, :except => [:create, :index]
      get '/photos/:id/image/:size' => 'photos#image'
      get '/photos/:id/display' => 'photos#display'

      resources :catalogs
      get '/catalogs/:id/dashboard' => 'catalogs#dashboard'
      get '/catalogs/:id/get_catalog' => 'catalogs#get_catalog'
      match "/catalogs/:id/edit" => "catalogs#edit", via: [:get, :post]
      get "/catalogs/:id/destroy" => "catalogs#destroy"
      get '/catalogs/authorize' => 'catalogs#authorize'
      get '/catalogs/authorize_callback' => 'catalogs#authorize_callback'

      #resources :localcatalogs, controller: 'catalogs', type: 'LocalCatalog', :concerns => :paginatable
      match '/catalogs/:id/import' => 'catalogs#import', via: [:get, :post]

      get '/locations/lookup'
      resources :locations, :concerns => :paginatable
      get '/locations/:id/view' => 'locations#view'


      post 'bucket/:id/add' => 'bucket#add'
      post 'bucket/:id/remove' => 'bucket#remove'
      get  'bucket/list' => 'bucket#list'
      get  'bucket' => 'bucket#index'
      get  'bucket/clear' => 'bucket#clear'
      get  'bucket/count' => 'bucket#count'
      get  'bucket/save' => 'bucket#save_to_album'
      get  'bucket/delete_photos' => 'bucket#delete_photos'

      get 'doubles/find'
      get 'doubles/index'
      get 'doubles/:doubles_id/delete/:photo_id' => 'doubles#delete'

      get 'administration/generate_albums'
      get 'administration/jobs_pending'
      get 'administration/list_jobs'

      post 'jobs/list' => 'jobs#list'
      resources :jobs

      require 'resque/server'
      mount Resque::Server.new, at: "/resque"


      root to: 'photos#index'

    end
```

In my log I get:

```
        Started GET "/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg" for ::1 at 2016-03-18 22:38:07 +0100

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/avatar/6/mh.jpg"):
      actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
      web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
      web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
      web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
      railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
      railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
      activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the initial slash?  `uploads/..` instead of `/uploads/...`

Comment: Yes i have. No change... without the '/' the path is prefixed with the model, which is 'users'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...it was this guy:

```
config.serve_static_files = false
```

when changing it to true, I forgot to restart the server....spent hours cos of this :-|